# paymenwall gateway integration with laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, omnipay

I tried to implement paymentwall gateway with laravel 5.1 using omnipay.But there is no exact documentation or sample codes available.Is there any implementation samples available for omnipay paymentwall integration with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation including usage examples in the class header files for the omnipay-paymentwall library.

#### Example

```
// Create a gateway for the PaymentWall REST Gateway
// (routes to GatewayFactory::create)
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PaymentWall');

// Initialise the gateway
$gateway->initialize(array(
    'apiType'      => $gateway::API_GOODS,
    'publicKey'    => 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY',
    'privateKey'   => 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY',
));

// Create a credit card object
// This card can be used for testing.
$card = new CreditCard(array(
            'firstName'             => 'Example',
            'lastName'              => 'Customer',
            'number'                => '4242424242424242',
            'expiryMonth'           => '01',
            'expiryYear'            => '2020',
            'cvv'                   => '123',
            'email'                 => 'customer@example.com',
            'billingPostcode'       => '4999',
));

// Do a purchase transaction on the gateway
$transaction = $gateway->purchase(array(
    'amount'                    => '10.00',
    'accountId'                 => 12341234,
    'currency'                  => 'AUD',
    'clientIp'                  => '127.0.0.1',
    'packageId'                 => 1234,
    'description'               => 'Super Deluxe Excellent Discount Package',
    'fingerprint'               => '*token provided by Brick.js*',
    'browserDomain'             => 'SiteName.com',
    'card'                      => $card,
));
$response = $transaction->send();
if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
    echo "Purchase transaction was successful!\n";
    $sale_id = $response->getTransactionReference();
    echo "Transaction reference = " . $sale_id . "\n";
}
```